# How to pass parameters into next screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

just started to learn React Native. Currently I am working on **createDrawerNavigator** . I am quite confuse how to pass parameter from one screen to another(FROM STOCKSCREEN TO STOCKLIST/VOLUME ANALYSIS). I refer to [this steps to do drawer navigation](https://blog.logrocket.com/navigating-react-native-apps-using-react-navigation/) .At the end of the steps , it stated about applying parameters but I do not know where to put the code...

***StockScreen.js (MainScreen)***

```
const StockNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
StockList: {
    screen: StockList, //HOW TO PASS PARAMETER (stock) TO THIS SCREEN?..
},
VolumeAnalysis: {
    screen: VolumeAnalysis, //HOW TO PASS PARAMETER (stock) TO THIS SCREEN?..

},
},{
    initialRouteName: "StockList"
});


class StockScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isFetched: false,
            stock: null,  //WANT TO PASS THIS AS PARAMETER             
        };    


        //I HAVE ADDED THIS ONE
        this.props.navigation.navigate('VolumeAnalysis', { stock:'newStock' })
    
    }

componentDidMount() {
  
    let url = [urls.api.st, '3'].join('/') + '?gg=1'

    fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) throw Error([response.status, response.statusText].join(' '))

            return response.json()
        })
        .then((body) => {
            this.setState({
                isFetched: true,
                stock: body.data, // DATA POPULATED
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => alert(error));
}

    render () {

     //DISPLAYING StockScreen DATA 

    
    }


}
```

**VolumeAnalysis.js** receiving the params (--HERE THE PARAMS KEEP GIVING ME NULL..)

```
render() {

    const { navigation } = this.props;    

    return  (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>{navigation.getParam('stock') }</Text>

        </View>
    )        
}
```

Really appreciate any helps, Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

That code to "store and pass" the data to another screen needs to be in some place that intends to switch the screen/route.

So, for example - once the data is loaded in one screen where loader is being shown, you might want the data to be passed on to next screen, i.e. `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })` from that article.

And you may add that in the `componentDidMount` - in the code you have given, inside a `.then`, where the data is resolved resulting into something like `this.props.navigation.navigate('VolumeAnalysis', { data:body.data })`, given this component is also one of the screens.

Then inside the `VolumeAnalysis` screen - you may check for any data in the navigator and store in the state, if there, using again the `componentDidMount` through - `const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('data', {})`, like in the article.

You may also consider using a global store to share the common-state using the libraries such as redux.

**:: Update ::**

The article you mentioned is outdated; The way mentioned above to get the parameters is for `4.x` and for newer version i.e. `5.x` (docs here - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop) - the parameters could be found in `route` prop passed in to the "screen-components". The example [here](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Route%20prop%20reference%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fnavigate.js) shows the usage;

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.. i followed what you said, but the parameter giving me null. From(StockScreen.js, data is there), when i send to VolumeAnalysis.js, receiving in componentDidMount..it giving me null..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useContext react hook to do this.

1. Create context file

```
import * as React from 'react';

const stock= {
    _stock: 'Null',
 
}

export const StockContext= React.createContext(stock);
```

2. Define context within your screens:

```
import { StockContext} from '../Contexts/StockContext'
```

3. Use react hook useContext to get data inside components:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';

 const StockContext= useContext(stock)
```

Comment: i have edited my question, please have a look... thank you..